# how to prevent resolvd from adding DNS servers from DHCP offer?

Tags: dhcp, openbsd

On my OpenBSD 7.1 router, I run `unbound` to resolve local domains to the local clients. I'd like the router itself to use the `unbound` daemon for lookups primarily as well, however `resolvd` adds the DHCP servers learned from the routers uplink, so that `/etc/resolvd.conf` looks like this:

```
nameserver <local-DNS-IP> # resolvd: cnmac0
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # resolvd: cnmac0
# Generated by cnmac0 dhclient
search local.home.example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
lookup file bind
```

It's the first 2 lines that I do not want in the file. Or at least need to move these `nameserver` entries below the localhost `nameserver` entry.

In my `/etc/dhclient.conf` I have the following section:

```
interface "cnmac0" {
  supersede domain-name "local.home.example.com";

  # Note: used to be 'supersede' however it should not matter here.
  prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
}
```

When `unwind` is running, `resolvd` does not add the DNS servers from the DHCP offer, however I cannot use that because `unbound` is used - `unwind` would take preference.

What are my choices ? (besides blocking `resolvd`)

Answer (score 2):

Is there something that you need in unbound that you can't do in unwind?

A few options:

You can disable resolvd and then just set the nameserver entries you want in resolv.conf directly.

If you want to keep resolvd running, you can try using the newish and most OpenBSDish way of managing this with the [dhcpleased](https://man.openbsd.org/dhcpleased.8) approach by adding this [dhcpleased.conf](https://man.openbsd.org/dhcpleased.conf.5) configuration:

```
/etc/dhcpleased.conf:

    interface cnmac0 {
        ignore dns
    }
```

As you mentioned, you could run unwind and set your preferred resolving nameserver and configs there.

If there's some extra functionality you need from unbound you could look at a 'drop-in' replacement built around unwind like [unwinder](https://github.com/horia/unwinder).